# Packagist package - cannot be updated/sync against GitHub

Tags: php, github, synchronization, packagist

Short question, I dont know where is to look for an answer.

I created a php package posted in packagist.

Today I created a new release (in the github repo) but the information on packagist.org cannot be updated.

The current release is 1.2 , but on packagist 1.1 is still the latest one.

I hit the "update" button on packagist and I am getting this error:

"An unexpected failure occurred"

or

"Another job is attempting to schedule immediately for this package, aborting scheduled-for-later update"

So sync is not working, any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

If someone else person is experiencing the same problem, the answer is ... JUST WAIT.

Yes that's it.

Seems that the messages we get are not quite descriptive of the situation, after an uncertain amount of time, packagist will be sync with GitHub.